# python solve the simultaneous equations with solutions > 0

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I have simultaneous equations(with many equations), which are no solution, and I need to find a best solutions. Each element of solution must>0 (no 0 or negative).

`np.linalg.lstsq` could get the best solution, but may also appear negative elements.

`scipy.optimize.nnls` could get best solution without negative elements, but may also appear 0.

How can I restrict to get the best solution with each element>0 or is there any other function can use to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For each parameter `p`, define `p_ = p - eps` for very small `eps`.

Solve for `{p_}`, then assign `p = p_ + eps` and you get all parameters above zero.

In practice, just add epsilon to the solution.

If that doesn't suffice, please explain why.